# codeigniter cache returns always empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I'm try to use the Codeigniter cache system, to cache some remote xml files into "file cache".

Every think looks great when I request the xmls, but codeigniter not cache the files, instead it return a empty cache, and the cache file contains just the data below:

```
a:3:{s:4:"time";i:1379515910;s:3:"ttl";i:120;s:4:"data";b:1;}
```

I'm using the code below to cache the xml:

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->cache->file->save('first', $data, 120);
```

**[UPDATED]**

Now I can save the cache, but I can't rescue the saved data. When I run the command below the cache return **false**

```
$this->cache->get('show');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `$this->cache->file->save('first', $data, 120);` return? If the save fails it will return false. Have you tried saving something simple to the cache like a string to check if it's working?

Comment: have you checked logs and permissions? Could be a permission issue.

Comment: I did, the log not show errors and the cache directory permissions is 777. I can save the cache, but I can't get it back.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->cache->get('first');` to get the data back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved, 
when I call the method to get the current cache I need to pass the used driver e.g.:

```
$this->cache->file->get('home');
OR
$this->cache->memcached->get('home');
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is the 'home' comes from? Could you explain the detail?
I got the same issue, always return false when get the cached file.

Comment: This makes no sense. Your code above saves the item as **first**, your original post tries to fetch a cache item named **show**, and your solution fetches an item named **home.** This answer is not good.

Answer (score 4):

You've saved it using

```
$this->cache->file->save('first', $data, 120);
```

Then get it using the right `key` and it should be `first`

```
$this->cache->get('first');
```

Also, to get information about `cache` you can use

```
var_dump($this->cache->cache_info());
```

Or you may use

```
var_dump($this->cache->get_metadata('first'));
```

This is useful for debugging.
The `get` method accepts `cache_item_id` as parameter that you have used when you saved it

```
get(id['string'])
```

Check the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html?highlight=caching).

Comment: The documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Just create folder "cache" in "application" directory. It works for me

Comment: The best thing is to check whether the cache folder exists as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but in my case it was storage problems.

my hdd was 100% full (because of some error logs).

Maybe this information will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled here with similar issue. My problem was that APC cache wasn't installed. So if anyone else is using APC and having this issue. Try installing APC.

Example PHP 7.1 on ubuntu 1604:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-apcu
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem too ...

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));
$this->cache->file->save('first', $data, 120);
```

I modified these two lines..